# Angular Js - Get a variable in Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ladder , my users are order by score and i use a variable in a ng-repeat to know the position of my user in ladder

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users| orderBy:'-score'" ng-init="pos=0">
  <td>{{pos + $index + 1}}</td>
  <td>{{user.email}}</td>
  <td>{{user.score}}</td>
<tr>
```

I want to keep this data in the controller , each user must have a rank

```
{{pos + $index + 1}}
```

Example :

```
{user : 
"score":12,
"email":test,
"rank": (result of var  {{pos + $index + 1}})
}
```

I want to know how to get the result of his value in my controller

Part 2

Thanks for you answers :)
But when i display the new value rank i got undefined

```
var User =  $resource('http://localhost:1337/user');
      var user = User.query(function(data){
          $scope.users = data;
          console.log("Try to display rank",$scope.users[0].rank);
}
```

In the console : Try to display rank undefined

It's strange because when i try :

```
 console.log("Try to display rank",$scope.users[0]);
```

I got :

Try to display rank {email
:
"test1",
firstName
:
test,
id
:
1,
isLogged
:
null,
lastName
:
null,
**rank**
:
4,
rankPrevious
:
null,
score
:
20}

Thanks

Comment: Try this `{{scopeVar = pos + $index + 1}}`

Comment: Did you try it ? Did it work or are you facing any problem?

Comment: how are you accessing the user in controller. is it on click?

Answer (score 0):

In html

```
{{user.rank = pos + $index + 1}}
```

above expression assigns result of `pos + $index + 1` to `user.rank` within user object. So, every `user` object have its own `rank` kept track seperatly.

In controller you can access each rank using

```
$scope.users[0].rank
$scope.users[1].rank
```

Comment: Wouldn't this override the `scopeVar` value for every `ng-repeat` iteration and only save the last one?

Comment: Thanks its work 'all my object have a new properties rank with good value , but when i try to use this new properties : console.log($scope.users[0].rank)  i got undefined

Comment: Did you try logging `console.log($scope.users[0])` and see what are all the properties available?

Comment: Yes i see all properties , i see rank too , but when i try to see console.log($scope.users[0].rank) i got undefined

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to execute this code.. can you show you code(update it in question seperatly)

Comment: Are you getting data from database before you log it?

Comment: Yes this data is from database

Comment: When you log user(0) in console is the data in JSON format or a JavaScript object? Can you verify.. Can you show me screenshot of console once you log user(0)?

Comment: Give me your email , i can't post screenshot

Comment: OK then just tell me whether its a json or a JavaScript object

Comment: Javascript object

Comment: Can you try to log other properties in the user object and see whether there are logging or not

Comment: If you are able to log other properties then you should be able to `rank` as well providing that you are indeed getting data from DB containing rank in it.